# Replace the work of a dependency injector on a concrete class by a factory

Tags: php, dependency-injection, factory

Currently I'm working on a PHP example and as dependency injector I'm using Auryn.

I have the following class that represents a concrete use case of an API call (for example, get all users from a database, get books or a not valid api request). This class depends on `ResponseMessageFactory` what builds the JSON response.

```
class NotValidApiCallUseCase implements Command{

    private $responseMessageFactory;

    public function __construct(ResponseMessageFactory $responseMessageFactory){
        $this->responseMessageFactory = $responseMessageFactory;
    }

    public function execute(){
        ...stuff...
    }

}
```

As I have many possible use case to resolve when I make an API call, my class responsible to route the current URL to an specific use case, use a factory to build the concrete use case.

```
class UseCaseFactory{

    public function __construct(ResponseMessageFactory $responseMessageFactory){
        $this->responseMessageFactory = $responseMessageFactory;
    }

    public function build($type){
        if($type == "INVALID_API_CALL"){
            return new NotValidApiCallUseCase($this->responseMessageFactory);
        }

        ... other if ...
    }

}
```

However, when I have to instantiate an use case, like I posted before, `NotValidApiCallUseCase`, I have to give him all dependencies so I'm breaking the work of my dependency injector.

Is it a bad idea? Am I not following the main purpose of an injector? How would I resolve it?

Comment: Auryn can delegate object instantiation to a factory, btw.